# When I use Epsilon GC, I cannot use Flight Recorder

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jfr

I'm running this command

```
java -cp "D:\Dev\Books Spaces\Java-11-and-12-New-Features-master\Chapter09" -XX:StartFlightRecording,filename=Epsilon.jfr -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseEpsilonGC exploring_further/TestFlightRecorder
```

The code runs, however the .jfr file is 0 bytes.

When I remove `-XX:+UseEpsilonGC` and Java defaults to G1 GC. the code runs and the flight recorder dump all the data to file and I can read it.

Why when I use Epsilon the file is empty and how Can I fix it.

On JDK 14 Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by hitting `Ctrl+C` while the code was running. the .jfr file gets populated and so I can read it. If I wait for OutOfMemoryError The file still 0 bytes.

Comment: It is also possible to use jcmd <pid> JFR.dump filename=dump.jfr to get a recording on demand, or you can specify -XX:StartFlightRecording:duration=100s and recording will be dumped after 100 s.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce on Oracle JDK 14.02 (Windows).

The file has zero size until the recording is dumped, which happens when the JVM exits (normally), so you need to wait for that.

If the application ends because an OutOfMemoryError, a recording can't be guaranteed, and if it happens, it is probably an emergency recording (which may lack information) and it is created with the prefix hs_oom_pid.